# Class Inheritance

Tags: oop

I wanted to know the technical reason why a parent object cannot be assigned to a child.
For eg :

```
Class Animal{}

Class Dog : Public Animal{}
```

`Animal a = new Dog()` is possible and but why

`Dog g = new Animal()` is not possible.

I know that, according to the above relationship Dog " is a " Animal but not Animal "is a" Dog. But what is the technical reason behind it. Why we can't assign it ?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "technical".

Comment: (very pseudo)Technically dog is a pointer to a memory location that contains a part that is the same as in animal objects, but also another part specific to dog objects. If you passed animal to dog pointer, you could allow calls to a part of the memory that is out of the one reserved for animal...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because dogs bark. Animals, in general, don't.

```
Dog g = new Animal();
g.bark();
```

How would `g` know to bark? Did the assignment magically turn the animal into a dog? What if it was a parrot? How do we turn parrots into dogs? Or if the assignment did not convert anything, how would the parrot know how to bark? (Note that this is a Norwegian Blue parrot, which doesn't really know how to do *anything*.)

Answer (score 2):

It's both logical and technical reason - an instance of `Animal` does not have all methods and fields of a `Dog`. For example:

```
class Animal {
    public int legs;
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    public int fangs;
}

Dog dog = new Animal();
dog.fangs = 5;
```

but you are using an `Animal`, which does not have `fangs`, so it would fail.

You *can* usually downcast though:

```
 public doSomethingDoggish(Animal animal) {
     ((Dog) animal).bark();
 }
```

But if you have not passed an instance of `Dog` there, it will fail at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Because then you could write

```
Animal animal = new Rabbit();
Dog d = animal;
d.bark(); // but it's a Rabbit
```

Answer (score 1):

the classic term is "IS-A" as in "a dog IS A(n) animal", but "an animal is NOT a dog", in your relationship.

That is intuitively why you can assign a dog to an animal, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Because your Dog is an Animal.

```
Dog g = new Dog()
```

You now have an Animal. It's a specific type of animal, but still an animal. It can do all the things that an animal can do.

If I want to treat it only as an Animal and ignore the fact that it's a Dog, I can do that with `Animal a = new Dog()`

An Animal isn't a Dog. It can't do all the things a Dog can do. So if I try to say `Dog g = new Animal()` ... I'm not making any sense. I'm trying to take away everything that makes a Dog a Dog.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are like contracts. When you define your `Animal` class you say something like "This is an Animal, he can do this". When you define `Dog`, you say "Dog is an Animal, He can do everything an Animal do, but he can also do that".

Now, when you do `Animal a = new Dog()` it is ok, since a `Dog` can do everything an `Animal` do.

But when you do `Dog g = new Animal()`, your breaking your contract, since an `Animal` can't do "that", only a `Dog` can.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for technical reasons, consider memory storage: "new Animal()" only requires enough resources to store the minimum data required by all animals, but "new Dog()" requires more resources -- the resources of a Mammal (fur, warm blood), and the resources of a Dog (fascination with squirrels).

If, though, you're asking "Once I've written 'Dog' once, why do I have to say it again?" then the answer is "not all languages require that."